# extracting characters before "." in a string containing two "."

Tags: r

I need to extract one letter before "." from hundred of strings. My input example is "R.GGGGSFGYSYGGGSGGGFSASSLGGGFGGGSK.G". It is tricky to me because there are two ".". My output file must contain two new columns indicating the which letter is before the first and the second period symbol.

To ease the understanding, what I need is:

R.GGGGSFGYSYGGGSGGGFSASSLGGGFGGGSK.G (column 1); R (column 2); K (column 3)

I appreciate any help.

Cheers,
L

Comment: Have you looked at `strsplit(my_string, "\\.")` and `substr`?

Comment: not much different than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53594867/only-keep-everything-between-two-in-r/53594928#53594928

Comment: `stringr::str_extract_all(your_string, pattern = "(.)\\.")` will pull out the letters with the dots. Easy to get rid of the dots in a second step.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the regexp: (.)\.

your expected results will be part of group 1 of the matched regexp.

https://regex101.com/r/BpLA5g/1